# Simple Python Code not working in Zapier Code function

Tags: python, python-3.x, zapier

I am having an issue with my code in `Zapier` application. I have written a fairly simple `if, elif`, and I am drawing incorrect outputs. If I declare the variables as `or`  the code works, but when using `input.get` which is a requirement, the code will always answer both even if the values are `null`.

The goal of the program is to determine if an item has a phone number, email or both. Any thoughts? I am fairly new to Python and code by Zapier so I am sure this is simple.

```
phoneTest = input.get('Phone')
emailTest = input.get('Email')

if(emailTest != '') and (phoneTest != ''):
    logic = 'both'
elif(emailTest == '') and (phoneTest != ''):
    logic = 'phone'
elif(emailTest != '') and (phoneTest == ''):
    logic = 'email'

output = [{'test': emailTest}]
```

**Python code in Zapier**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even if the values are null

Your code is checking specifically against the empty string, not null (None). So yes, if the items are null, its going to say both. Try doing a "truthy" check instead of specifically the empty string.

```
phoneTest = input.get('Phone')
emailTest = input.get('Email') 

if emailTest and phoneTest: 
    logic = 'both'
elif phoneTest: 
    logic = 'phone'
elif emailTest: 
    logic = 'email'

 output = [{'test': emailTest, 'logic': logic}]
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick Humrich